# Can thesaurus items have more than one USE relation?

Tags: modeling, hierarchy, linking

I want to model a Thesaurus using the ANSI/NISO standard relation description like "broader term", "narrow term", etc. ([see this Wikipedia article for details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thesaurus#Standards_and_manuals)). Is it valid for a Thesaurus item in this description standard to have more than one "use" relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

`USE` is for mapping entry vocabulary to authorized terms. It's an equivalency relationship. Therefore `1:1`.  `Use for` is just the opposite; it defines a specific term to be used instead of (often) multiple common terms.  e.g. you might have `('vermilion: USE 'red)`, or you could have `('red: USE-FOR 'pink, 'vermilion, 'rose)`.